# How do I get C++ builder?

Tags: windows, c++, rad

I went to download C++ builder, where it says, *Download the Free C++Builder Community Edition* but when I went to download, it's an executable called `radstudio_10_3_3_esd7899_nt.exe` then I went to install, and it has only Delphi available, like below image. What am I missing?

[image]